# Save label.text in swift4

Tags: ios, swift

Im currently developing a iOS app in which im going to keep track of our warehouse stock. It's a pretty simple app an just contains a lable and an stepper. The app is pretty much finished, but i don't get how to save the changed value of the label. I want to save it automatically so that when someone presses the "+" on the stepper, the value should save without pressing a extra save button

Current code:

```
//montageplatte
@IBOutlet weak var lbl_montageplatte: UILabel!
@IBAction func stepper_montageplatte(_ sender: UIStepper)
{
    lbl_montageplatte.text = Int(sender.value).description
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _save_?

Comment: I also don't get it. If you set the value of your variable it's normally fine.

Comment: Like when they close the app, the value should be saved. At the moment the value resets when the app gets closed.

Comment: @kapg : explains `save`. you mean to save it locally, or you have backend running, wanna use core data/sqlite/ local files/user defaults what are the options u considered so far. If you havent considered any of these so far try read upon them

Comment: Then you probably need to save it in a database or something like that because every time you start the app, the value gets reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save it in `UserDefaults`.

```
@IBAction func stepper_montageplatte(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    lbl_montageplatte.text = Int(sender.value).description

    UserDefaults.standard.set(String(sender.value), forKey: "lblMontageplatte")
}
```

To get back value you can do as follow...

```
if let lblValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lblMontageplatte") as? String {

   print(lblValue)
   lbl_montageplatte.text = lblValue
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now it saves the value. But when I press the "+" or "-" after a app restart, the value resets to zero. Any solution for that?

Comment: you need to add this code in `viewDidLoad:` method of your viewctonroller. `if let lblValue = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "lblMontageplatte") as? String {

   print(lblValue)
   lbl_montageplatte.text = lblValue
}`

Comment: Already did that, but it still resets to zero when I'm pressing the stepper again

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

In the custom cell create an outlet for the stepper and a `NSKeyValueObservation` property

```
@IBOutlet weak var stepper : UIStepper!
var stepperObservation : NSKeyValueObservation?
```

In `cellForRow` in the controller add the key value observer

```
cell.stepperObservation = cell.stepper.observe(\.value, options: [.new]) { (stepper, change) in
    print(change.newValue!)
}
```

Rather than printing the new value update the model (the item for the particular index path) and save the datasource array if necessary.